# Reading only headers from csv

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to read only headers from a csv file using [CSVHELPER](https://github.com/JoshClose) but i am unable to get `GetFieldHeaders()` method of csvhelper.

I have taken code from this link :[Source](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23691049/CSV-file-reading-only-specific-columns-and-writing-to-Data-Set-c.html)

```
 public static String[] GetHeaders(string filePath)
        {
            using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv")))
            {
                int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;

                string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();//Error:doesnt contains definition
            }
        }
```

But **GetFieldHeaders** is not working.

**Note**: I only want to read headers from csv file

**Update** : Headers in my csv files are like below :

```
Id,Address,Name,Rank,Degree,Fahrenheit,Celcius,Location,Type,Stats
```

So can anybody tell me what i am missing??

Comment: This is extension library and you should contact with author. But, I suggest you should using StreamReader and ReadLine method.

Comment: @HienNgo :I have posted here because may be somebody have used it and i can get an answer

Comment: could you please post contents of your `data.csv`?
also, did you set `csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;`?

Comment: @a-man:I updated my question to include headers for csv file.can you please post any code which shows how to read only headers and not records from csv file as there are millions of records in my csv file

Comment: I saw in [ CsvHelper/src/CsvHelper.Tests/Reading/MultipleHeadersTests.cs] of author. Did you try csv.ReadHeader() ?

Comment: @JohnG:I am not using for this purpose only.later on i need to do lots of things with csv files and i have already used it for other task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below code ... hope this will help you.

```
var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("YOUR FILE PATH"));           
csv.ReadHeader();          
var headers = csv.Parser.RawRecord;
```

Note: `headers` will return all headers together.. you will need to make substring(s) for each comma to get each header separately.

Comment: Yes this worked.Thank you so much for the answer.thanks alot

Comment: For anyone having troubles nowadays, CsvHelper doesn't allow anymore to use csv.ReadHeader() before calling csv.Read() first, if you do it, it'll throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try to use this library. But quick overview of documentation brought this possible solution:

```
public static String[] GetHeaders(string filePath)
    {
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv")))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
            int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;

            string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
        }
    }
```

* See [documentation](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) and search for `header`.

Comment: Where did you find this method : GetFieldHeaders();??

Comment: I have added single line `csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;`. Rest of the code is yours. Probably you have to implement that if you have not yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadHeaders(string path)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
            if (csv.Read())
                return csv.FieldHeaders;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

All of the methods in the other answers seem to have been removed in the latest version?
This is what worked for me:

```
using (var fileReader = File.OpenText("data.csv"))
{
    var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader);
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    string[] headers = ((CsvFieldReader)((CsvParser)csv.Parser).FieldReader).Context.HeaderRecord;
}
```